# How to set nextFocus listener in Android AutoCompleteTextview widgets

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I'm newbie to android development,I have an issue in AutoCompleteTextView  Widget.Is it Possible to set the NextFocus for autocompleteTextView,Hereby mentioned which code i was used, Kindly help me to resolve this issue, Thanks in Advance.

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/autocomple_textview"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.5"
                android:completionThreshold="1"
                android:hint="Site Name"
                android:nextFocusDown="@+id/edittext"
                android:singleLine="true" >
                 <requestFocus />
            </AutoCompleteTextView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This Code, The **android:nextFocusDown="@+id/edittext"**  is not applicable for the AutoCompleteTextView, So you have to change this into **android:imeOptions="actionNext"**, I have the mentioned the working code below, Please Implement this.

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
                        android:id="@+id/aTxt_UserName"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="25dip"
                        android:padding="5dip"
                        android:hint="User Name"
                        android:singleLine="true" 
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                        android:background="#3a8925" >

                    </AutoCompleteTextView>
```